# Como obter imagem do ACTION_ATTACH_DATA

Tags: android

Gostaria de poder conseguir sanar esse problema que estou, bem vamos lá, estou fazendo um app de Wallpapers simples, que tem sua própria galeria de imagens online, o app está praticamente concluído o problema agora é, eu quero que meu app pegue imagens da galeria também porém sem ser via intent, aquelas que abrem o gerenciador, no android tem a opções na galeria de compartilhar(share) e o usar como/definir como (set as) até aqui tudo bem, olhem a imagem abaixo, 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem é o aplicativo de galeria do Google Fotos, nos 3 pontos do canto superior há um menu de opções(FOTO ABAIXO):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo que clicar em "usar como" aparece as opções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui fazer minha aplicação aparecer nesse "set as"

```
<activity android:name=".Main.SetWpfora">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Meu problema é como eu faço para receber esse attach_data/imagem na minha activity ?

Eu fiz algo parecido, porém ao invés de usar :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA" />
```

eu usei `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />` porém o send é para compartilhamento, eu queria algo mais especifico por isso tentei usar attach_data, com o send eu consegui pegar a imagem a minha main activity ficou assim:

```
public class SetWpfora extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_wpfora);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageVisualizer);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
        Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de passar quase o dia todo pesquisando consegui a resolução para o problema tão simples, mas difícil de encontrar, para obter a imagem precisei apenas dessa linha:

```
Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
```